# Discord Bot Not Responding to Commands (Python)

Tags: python, command, discord, bots

I've just gotten into writing discord bots. While trying to follow online instructions and tutorials, my bot would not respond to commands. It responded perfectly fine to on_message(), but no matter what I try it won't respond to commands. I'm sure it's something simple, but I would appreciate the help.

```
import discord
from discord.ext.commands import Bot
from discord.ext import commands

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='$')
TOKEN = '<token-here>'

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f'Bot connected as {bot.user}')
    
@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.content == 'test':
        await message.channel.send('Testing 1 2 3')
        
@bot.command(name='go')
async def dosomething(ctx):
    print("command called") #Tried putting this in help in debugging
    await message.channel.send("I did something")


        
bot.run(TOKEN)
```

[Picture of me prompting the bot and the results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AmVlU.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. First of all, the only import statement that you need at the top is `from discord.ext import commands`. The other two are not necessary.

Second of all, I tried messing around with your code myself and found that the `on_message()` function seems to interfere with the commands so taking that out should help.

Third of all, I only found this out when I duplicated one of my own working bots and slowly changed all of the code until it was identical to yours. For some reason python didn't like it when I just copied and pasted your code. I have never seen something like this before so I honestly don't know what to say other than that your code is correct and should work as long as you take the `on_message()` function out.

Here's the final code that I got working:

```
from discord.ext import commands

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix="$")
TOKEN = "<token-here>"


@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f'Bot connected as {bot.user}')


@bot.command()
async def dosomething(ctx):
    await ctx.send("I did something")

bot.run(TOKEN)
```

As you can see the only things that I have changed from your code are that I removed the redundant imports at the top, and I deleted the `on_message()` function. It works perfectly like this on my end so I would suggest that you re-type it out like this in a new file and see if that works.

If that doesn't work for you then my next guess would be that there is a problem with your installation of `discord.py` so you might try uninstalling it and then reinstalling it.

If none of that helps let me know and I will see if I can help you find anything else that might be the cause of the problem.

Comment: Thank you very much! I tried it and got it to work.

Comment: Great! Glad I could help! Would you be able to mark the answer as correct then please?

Answer (score 16):

I made the same mistake at first.

```py
@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.content == 'test':
        await message.channel.send('Testing 1 2 3')
```

This function overiding the on_message event so it is never sent to bot.command()

To fix it you just have to add await bot.process_commands(message) at the end of the on_message function:

```
async def on_message(message):
    if message.content == 'test':
        await message.channel.send('Testing 1 2 3')
    await bot.process_commands(message)
```

Haven't tested yet but that should fix your issue.

Comment: Thank you so much, also been stuck.

Answer (score 1):

just put client.process_commands(message)

in on_message event at last..

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).